# How to find the important locations of two matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning

I have two matrices `A` and `B`, the size of which are both `50*1000 double`. Matrices `A` and `B` are fMRI data matrices. The value in the two matrices are activation values. `50` represents the number of time points, and `1000` represents the number of features.I want to use manifold learning (or any other machine learning methods) to find the important common locations of matrices `A` and `B`. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You should determine what is a common location first.

Comment: @Vesper, the common locations mean that the location means something to both matrix A and matrix B. If I know the value in this  location in A, I can also know something in the same location in B.

Comment: Well, this "Somehing" is what's required to be documented. Apparently those time points are pretty different in different matrices, so plain comparing time doesn't give you a thing about the data. I also wonder why the data size is so small, given fMRI provides quite a lot of data. Maybe you're comparing a 2D slice to another 2D slice?

Comment: @Vesper, yes, fMRI data is quite large, I just make it small. I want to learn how to apply manifold leaning to the fMRI data.